# is there any chance to submit ajax form with a div element and not with input type submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form and a div outside the form. before I subjected the form with `$(".btn-update.")click()` but now with `$(".btn-update").ajaxForm()` can not submit the form.

html code:

```
<form id="company-profile-edit-form" name="company-profile-edit-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="updateProfileAction.php" method="POST">
    <label>
        Company Name: <span class="req">*</span>
    </label>
    <input name="company-name" type="text" value="{companyName}" />
</form>
```

Update profile

js code:

```
$('.btn-update').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('<div class="loader"><img src="./resources/images/loader.gif" /></div>').appendTo(".main-backend .popups");
        $(".loader").toggle();
    },
    beforeSubmit: function () {
        var firstName = $("input[name=first-name]", "#company-profile-edit-form").val();

        if ((email === "")) {
            $('.error-message').css({
                'display': 'block'
            });
            $(".error-message span").html('Ups! You forgot to populate fields that are required!');
            $('.error-message').fadeIn('slow', function () {
                $('.error-message').delay(7000).fadeOut('slow');
            });
            return false;
        }

    },
    success: function (data) {
        $(".loader").remove();

        $("#company-profile-edit-form")[0].reset();
        $(".company-profile-edit-close").remove();
        $(".edit-profile").remove();
        $(".op").toggle();
    }
});
```

How I can submit the form with  `<div class="btn-update">Update profile</div>` ?

thanks to all

Comment: Breaking keyboard navigation not using an element that can be selected, not all users use a mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ajaxForm have to be assigned to your form, not the button.

Then, just assign an "onclick" event to your "btn-update" (by the way: better for id, avoid to submit by class since id it's unique while you can assign same class to multiple items) and inside a normal subit.

So:

```
$('#company-profile-edit-form').ajaxForm({ ...
```

and

```
$( '.btn-update' ).click(function() {
   $('#company-profile-edit-form').submit();
});
```

Comment: it is possible to implement this function, the validate ()?

Comment: move validation's logic before submit. So, do your checks in "click" function, set a var isValidated = true, validate your form (if any error, isValidated = false) and finally sorround the submit call in a condition: if (isValidated){ $('#company...').submit()}. That is!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can!

Try to bind the [click function](http://api.jquery.com/click/) to the div.

```
<div id="update" class="btn-update">Update profile</div>
```

And the js:

```
$( "#update" ).click(function() {
     $('#company-profile-edit-form').submit();
});
```

Remember to **replace the alert with your submit function!**

Comment: but i need use .ajaxForm() and not .click() .

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/submit/ look for the first sample: A div outside the form. And there is the answer:

```
<form id="target" action="destination.html">
<input type="text" value="Hello there">
<input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
<div id="other">
Trigger the handler
</div>


$( "#other" ).click(function() {
$( "#target" ).submit();
});
```

Comment: i have a function formProfile(){
  $(formId).ajaxForm(
code...
);
}

i do how?

$( "#other" ).click(function() {
formProfile();
});

Answer (score 0):

### First, the .ajaxForm should be used on the `<form>` itself.

So, it should be `$('#company-profile-edit-form').ajaxForm({});`

### Next, you need to use .submit() to simulate a form submission

```
$('.btn-update').click(function(e){
    $('#company-profile-edit-form').submit();
});
```